# How can I extract the actual values from a database call for subsequent processing?

Tags: laravel

Apologies for such a vague question title, but I don't know the correct terminology to use for the problem I've got.

I'm developing a search function within which growers enter the name of their crop, the database is probed for the ID for that crop, and a second database call returns factsheets that are associated with that crop ID.

Usually, only one ID will be returned, but for some crops (e.g. asian pear, european pear), two IDs will be returned if the grower enters "pear".

My code returns the requisite ID(s), but I'm having trouble "extracting" the actual ID values from what is being returned (I don't know its name - it looks like objects within an array).

So my code

```
$cropID = Crop::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->select('id')
    ->get();
```

returns, for $search = "pear",

```
$cropID = [{"id":4},{"id":112}]
```

I want to get the id values into a structure that I can loop through to search for factsheets associated with each ID, eg.

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value)
{
  ... do stuff with $value
}
```

What do I have to do with $cropID to smooth the way to subsequently get a foreach loop (if that's the correct approach) to work?

Thanks, Tom.

Comment: Cant you do `foreach ($crops as $crop) { // use $crop->id }`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this solution please - I can't work out how to modify my current code to incorporate your guidance. Thanks/Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$crops = Crop::where('name','like','%'.$search.'%')
    ->select('id')
    ->get();

foreach($crops as $crop) {
  echo $crop->id;
  // Factsheet::where('crop_id', $crop->id)->get();
}
```

Or you can pluck it out

```
$cropIds = $crops->pluck('id');
foreach($cropIds as $id) {
  echo $id;
  // Factsheet::where('crop_id', $id)->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. Cheers, Tom.